# How to translate the following sentence?

Tags: translation

> ...a list of the ten most common and effective strategies resorted to by the agendas "hidden" to establish a manipulation of the population through the media.

I understand the beginning and the end of above text, but the middle is incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather convoluted, isn't it?

... **a list of** (what?)
**the ten most common and effective strategies** (describe them!)
**resorted to** (by whom? by what?)
**by the agendas** (which ones?)
**"hidden"** (why?)
**to establish** (what?)
**a manipulation** (of whom? of what?)
**of the population** (by what ways?)
**through the media**.

The part that starts with "resorted to" is called a relative clause, and a connecting relative pronoun can be restored to make it read

> ... a list of the ten ... strategies ***which are*** resorted to by...

The "resorted to" is a past participle (pointing to passive voice) from the verb "*resort* [to]" meaning "use in desperation" or "use as final available option".